# How to get ERRORLEVEL of a command in forfiles?

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel, forfiles

I need to handle files older than a day. Thereforw I use this:

```
forfiles -m %%~nxf /C "cmd /c start /wait /MIN 7z.exe t %%f" /d +1
```

Now I'd like to check if the progress of 7z.exe succeeded. How can I get the `errorlevel` of the command inside the forefiles command? Is there any possibility?

I already tried following ways which did not work. `errorlevel` always returns 0, even if I use broken files, that should return an error (2).

```
forfiles -m %%~nxf /C "cmd /c start /wait /MIN 7z.exe t %%f && echo ok || echo delete %%f" /d +1

forfiles -m %%~nxf /C "cmd /c start /wait /MIN 7z.exe t %%f && if errorlevel 2 (DEL %%f)" /d +1
```

Comment: Don't use `start` at all, just execute `7z` directly like `cmd /c 7z.exe .............`

Comment: use `||` immediately after the call to `7z.exe` to catch instances where it doesn't succeed

Comment: 7z.exe t %%f belongs together so this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `7z.exe` does really deliver an `ErrorLevel`, I think that the conditional command separators query the `ErrorLevel` of `cmd` rather than of `7z.exe`. The following should work:

```
forfiles /M "%%~nxf" /C "cmd /C 0x22start /WAIT /MIN 7z.exe t 0x22%%~f0x22 && echo ok || echo delete 0x22%%~f0x220x22" /D +1
```

Or you can do that also without `start`:

```
forfiles /M "%%~nxf" /C "cmd /C 0x227z.exe t 0x22%%~f0x22 && echo ok || echo delete 0x22%%~f0x220x22" /D +1
```

As you might have noticed, I also fixed some quote issues for the given paths.